# Cannot invoke initializer for type... Only while compiling for tests

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a class that has a few init methods and, after adding a new variable and therefore a new init, I began getting the following error only when I'm compiling to run the unit tests (I can compile and run my app without getting that error):

```
Overloads for 'SearchedLocation' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (invocation: NSInvocation?), (selector: Selector), ()
```

My class is:

```
class SearchedLocation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let address : String?
    let neighborhood : String?
    let city : String
    let fullAddress : String?
    let name : String?

//    ....

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, address: String, neighborhood: String, city: String, fullAddress: String) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.address = address
    self.neighborhood = neighborhood
    self.city = city
    self.fullAddress = fullAddress
    self.name = ""
}

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, address: String, neighborhood: String, city: String, fullAddress: String, name: String?) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.address = address
    self.neighborhood = neighborhood
    self.city = city
    self.fullAddress = fullAddress

    if name != nil && !name!.isEmpty {
        if self.fullAddress!.contains(name!) {
            self.name = ""
        } else {
            self.name = name!
        }
    } else {
        self.name = ""
    }
}
```

And this is where I'm getting the error:

```
let place = SearchedLocation(coordinate: (placemark?.coordinate)!, address: address, neighborhood: placemark!.subLocality!, city: placemark!.locality!, fullAddress: fullAddress)
```

That code was working just fine (even when running the tests) until I added the last init method to the class.. And now even when I comment it I keep getting that error.

Anyone has any idea of what it is about?

Comment: Are you using any form of version control? Swift compiler errors can get notoriously cryptic; the slightest, most subtle change can tick the compiler off. I realize that this comment probably isn't helpful, but in the spirit of reminders, are you sure you can't undo this?

Comment: Hahahaha for a Second I thought it could be something with Git (yes, I'm using it!). Gonna give a try to see if the compiler is just moody....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After undoing my changes I realized that I had created a test class named "SearchedLocation", just as my class. So that's why I was getting that error only when compiling to run the tests.

Stupid error :(